Showing HTML diffs as part of PR reviews on Bitbucket
We have a Haskell backend codebase at work, and I've started to try to make any comments/docs Haddock compatible, so then we can go and generate nice HTML docs for our internal libraries/components.
Whilst Haddock is designed to be readable straight from the source code, little errors, like forgetting to escape special characters, are only clear if you read the generated HTML. And the generated HTML is just a nicer format to read, formatted code blocks + hyperlinks are easier to navigate through than a block of text (much like on StackOverflow, the generated HTML is nicer to read than the raw markdown).
I'd like my team members to be able to see the HTML generated docs AS HTML as part of reviewing my PR, and also see the diff between them (maybe by some green/red highlighting where appropriate).
I don't mind of course if they can still see the text diff between the old and new docs as well, but I'd like to them to be able to view the as HTML, without having to navigate away from the PR/generate the docs etc.
I feel if the generated docs/diff were directly visible as part of the PR, there will be more effort to keep them up-to-date and nicely formatted+readable. Which is good, particularly for new team members to get up to speed with the codebase.
Is there anyway I can coerce Bitbucket into doing this?

Server or cloud? On cloud at least you could make your own plugin that might be able to do that
